# Merge files in SPSS - key variable

Tags: spss

I merged a few files in SPSS with the same ID number. I made sure that the ID numbers were sorted ascending in each file. The names of the IDs are the same in every file and the variables contain exact the same numbers. Is it a problem that the width, number of decimals and number of columns differ between the files? Or do I have to make sure that al these features are the same in the files?

Answer (score 0):

When using `match files` you need the `BY` variables to have the same type in all files (for string variables only, that also includes size).
Additionally, you can't have any other variables in the files, who have the same name but conflicting types.